# Mocking a Laravel Facade that calls a method from the Facade itself

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, mockery

I'm currently in the process of writing unit tests for a Trait. This Trait included a method called registryPersist() which in tern calls a Facade method called Registry::persist(). This method as the name implies saves the registry value to the database and then calls Registry::set() in order to set the registry to the local scope. It is a fairly straight forward procedure.

I tried following the suggestion from the Laravel docs and mocking the Registry::persist() method with the following code:

```
Registry::shouldReceive('persist')->with('test', 'ok', 'model.users')
```

However given that *persist* also calls *set* i get the **BadMethodCallException** exception because *set* is not mocked. (*Received RegistryAccessControl::set(), but no expectations were specified*)

The official mockery docs suggest to create a mock instance how ever this will  not work because when i actually try to call the Trait method, the facade is not mocked.

```
$user = factory(User::class)->create();
$user->registrySet('test', 'ok');
```

The Trait Method:

```
public function registryPersist(string $name, $value): void
{
    Registry::persist(
        $name,
        $value,
        $this->getNamespace()
    );
}
```

Is there any way to effectively test this method?

Furthermore, given that *registrySet()* only forwards the parameters to the Facade do you think that the test that im trying to write is a good idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yea, set up sqlite in memory db and hit it. Good luck! :)

Comment: So, basically you are suggesting to turn this in to an integration test

Comment: Yea; basically mock only things that you do not own and you dont want to “hit”; like 3rd party API. When you mock stuff you are most likely testing “how good your mocks are”; not the actual thing. Also I am a stranger on the internet; consult with more senior people in your company.